# Why is answer #25472 upvoted? How is it in any way useful to the question?

Tags: discussion, quality-control, specific-post

A recent post ("[Is this hadith aunthentic? "...so seek treatment (of illness) but do not treat (illness) with anything that is haraam."](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/25469/22)") is asking a fairly concise question: Is such-and-such hadith authentic?

To the best of my knowledge, "authentic" has a [very particular meaning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadith_terminology#.E1.B9.A2a.E1.B8.A5.C4.AB.E1.B8.A5) in the hadith sciences; in order to be "authentic" a very strict set of criteria must be adhered to.

Currently, there's two answers: [One](https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/25471/3487) cites an explicit claim about the authenticity as per the judgement of a known hadith scholar, and it currently only has one vote.  The [second](https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/25472/3487) (#25472), with *three* upvotes, provides *absolutely no credible claims* about the hadith's authenticity; despite that, it is currently the *top-voted answer* on the thread.

It does, however, quote a number of completely different ahadith from the one the questioner was actually asking about; but again there is absolutely no attempt to establish authenticity of those. But that's mostly irrelevant, since even if the general meaning of the *matn* is confirmed as reliable, *that does not make the original hadith authentic*.

Does this answer deserve to be representative of this site for a question of this nature? Does it provide any value for the academic study of Islam? As I see it, this post — as well as the votes it has garnered — demonstrate such a lack of understanding of the hadith sciences that it would only serve to further discredit this site in the eyes of actual *experts*.

---

**Update:**

Since it's been over a week, and absolutely nobody has presented an argument in its favor, it has now been deleted.

Answer (score 1):

> Does this answer deserve to be representative of this site for a question of this nature?

No.

> Does it provide any value for the academic study of Islam?

Barely.

And what should be done about the answer?

Down-voted, flagged as "not an answer" and voted for deletion.